# SCSS randomly stops compiling partials

Tags: css, sass

I have the following file structure:

```
/dir/style.css
/dir/scss/style.scss
/dir/scss/_fonts.scss
/dir/scss/_footer.scss
/dir/scss/_header.scss
/dir/scss/_home.scss
/dir/scss/_vars.scss
```

I import each partial in my style.css like `@import "fonts";` and run `sass --watch dir/scss:dir` to compile style.scss to style.css. At first this works as intended and making a change in style.scss or any imported partial causes everything to compile to style.css, but seemingly randomly changes I make in partials stop getting tracked. Editing a partial still results in a compile success message on the command line, but the new changes made in the partial weren't actually compiled. It will continue to not work until I restart the watch command.

Edit: Code editor is vscode. Sass version 1.13.0 compiled with dart2js 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are running into a caching issue with the browser you are trying to see these changes on?  I have this issue sometimes when compiling SCSS or JS with webpack.  I know with Chrome, Shift+F5 refreshes and clears the cache.  Also in the dev tools(F12) there is an option inside the network tab to disable the cache while the dev tools are open.

Comment: Nope, the new changes are literally not compiling into css. I open the css file and ctrl + f to check this.

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Also what are you using to compile your SASS?

Comment: I'm using vscode. Sass version 1.13.0 compiled with dart2js 2.0.0